# Case sql column calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying a calculation as a column, but seems to fail .There is no column called gap

the line is

```
case d.gap when  a.actual_value IS TRUE then (quar_target - a.actual_value) else 'NULL' END ,
```

---

The entire script is

```
SELECT    
    weekly.* ,
    quarterly.target_value as quar_target
FROM  ( 
    SELECT a.week_id,
           d.region_id,
           d.region_name,
           d.metric_id  ,
           case d.metric_desc 
               when 'BE GMV Lift' then 'GMV Lift'
               when 'B2C GMV Lift' then 'GMV Lift' 
               when 'Trust GMV Lift' then 'GMV Lift' 
               else d.metric_desc
           end as metric_desc,
           case d.gap 
               when  a.actual_value IS TRUE 
                   then (quar_target - a.actual_value) 
                else 'NULL' END,
           d.ini_name     ,
           a.actual_value ,
           a.actual_txt   ,
           a.target_value ,
           a.target_txt   ,
           a.signals       ,
           a.comments                       
    FROM       
       -- Get  most recently reported records. If the metric is not reported for this week, get the last reported number 
        ( SELECT  *
          FROM    l1_weekly_entry   
          WHERE week_id=WEEK(CURDATE(), 1) - 1
        )   a
```

I am trying to introduce a column d.gap

Comment: what does "but seems to fail " actually mean?

Comment: May be your alias "d" doesn't have column "gap" just check

Comment: yes !! #1054 - Unknown column 'd.gap' in 'field list

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am getting is you want to have a new column `gap` that is not already in `d`, you can introduce it like this in the select list

```
..., gap = (case when  a.actual_value IS TRUE 
                   then (quar_target - a.actual_value) 
                else 'NULL' END), ...
```

You cannot introduce a column with alias like `d.gap` because it does not belong to any table.

So your full query would be like this

```
SELECT    
    weekly.* ,
    quarterly.target_value as quar_target
FROM  ( 
    SELECT a.week_id,
           d.region_id,
           d.region_name,
           d.metric_id  ,
           case d.metric_desc 
               when 'BE GMV Lift' then 'GMV Lift'
               when 'B2C GMV Lift' then 'GMV Lift' 
               when 'Trust GMV Lift' then 'GMV Lift' 
               else d.metric_desc
           end as metric_desc,
           gap = case when  a.actual_value IS TRUE 
                   then (quar_target - a.actual_value) 
                else 'NULL' END,
           d.ini_name     ,
           a.actual_value ,
           a.actual_txt   ,
           a.target_value ,
           a.target_txt   ,
           a.signals       ,
           a.comments                       
    FROM       
       -- Get  most recently reported records. If the metric is not reported for this week, get the last reported number 
        ( SELECT  *
          FROM    l1_weekly_entry   
          WHERE week_id=WEEK(CURDATE(), 1) - 1
        )   a
```

The same worked for `d.metric_desc` because this column is in your table

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to writting `END` for case when in many of places in your answer.
Eg.

```
case d.gap when  a.actual_value IS TRUE then (quar_target - a.actual_value) else 'NULL' END
```

Likewise.

**MSDN:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

**Syntax With Exmple:**

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'd.gap' in 'field list, I am getting this error

Comment: this simply means that alies d does not have column gap in it. Look at the table structure for it.

Comment: I simply need to create a new column that does a difference target - actual which are columns in table